# Identicality of moments of the limit of a random sequence and of its subsequence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n$ and $X$ be random variables for which $EX_n^p \rightarrow EX^p <\infty$ for $p\in \{1, \ldots, P\}$. $\{X_n\}$ is bounded in probability (this can be shown noting that $EX_n^2 = O(1)$ and applying Markov's inequality), hence by Prokhorov's theorem, each subsequence has a further subsequence, say $\{Y_n\}$, that converges weakly to a limit $Y$. We can show that the moment convergence is also true for $Y_n$: $EY_n^p \rightarrow EY^p <\infty$ for $p\in \{1, \ldots, P\}$.

The claim is that "the moments of $Y$, for $p\in \{1, \ldots, P\}$, are identical to the moments of $X$". How can I show the veracity of this claim?

Comment: What if we have $\{X_n\}$ iid and two other variables $X$ and $Z$ that have the same first $P$ moments as $X_1$, but $E[X^{P+1}]\neq E[Z^{P+1}]$? So $Y$ cannot have the same $P+1$ moment as both $X$ and $Z$.

Comment: @Michael, I edited the question to address the issue you raised.

Comment: I don't think understand the question. $(Y_n)_n$ is a subsequence of $(X_n)_n$? That is, there exists an increasing $\varphi$ such that $Y_n = X_{\varphi(n)}$ for every $n$? If so,for every $p$ we get that $\mathbb{E} Y_n^p$ is a subsequence of $\mathbb{E} X_n^p$, don't we?

Comment: @Javad : Your edit makes more sense.  In addition to Clement's further question, it is not clear if the subsequence indices $n[k]$ are chosen deterministically, or after looking at the random sequence outcome, to form the subsequence $\{X_{n[k]}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$. If deterministically, we have $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}E[X_{n[k]}^p]= E[X^p]$ for all $p \in \{1, ..., P\}$, else  we do not necessarily have that (since, for example, we can have $\{X_n\}$ iid Bernoulli  and choose $X_n$ to be part of the subsequence only when $X_n=0$).

Comment: @ClementC. Indeed! Your simple observation that I overlooked is actually the answer: $EY_n^p$ is itself a subsequence of $EX_n^p$ and hence converges to the same limit, therefore $EY_n^p \rightarrow EX^p = EY^p$.

Comment: @Javad Yes, indeed.

Comment: @Michael, good point. I suppose the indices are assumed to be chosen deterministically.

Comment: What if $X_n = n$ with probability $1/n^2$, and $0$ with probability $1-1/n^2$, and $X$ is Gaussian with mean 0 and variance $1$.  Then $E[X_n]\rightarrow 0$ and $E[X_n^2] \rightarrow 1$ but $X_n$ converges in distribution to $Y=0$ (perhaps "in distribution" is what you mean by "weakly"?) and $E[Y^2]=0\neq 1$.